Angular Material Tabs Inconsistency in Angular 17
In the example at https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview, there is a distinct static line under the button labels. When changing tabs the selected button label is underlined in a color based on the selected theme.
What I’m referring to is the static line. In my code this line never appears. In my opinion, the result is that it doesn’t look much like a tab control.
I’m using Angular Material extensively and have had no issues with any of the other components. Does anyone know to fix this?
I’ve tried isolating by creating a new Angular 17 application with nothing other than a basic tab group.

That underline comes from the mat-mdc-tab-label-container global style. Is it possible you've overridden that style? Also, the color from the underline is set by the --mat-tab-header-divider-color CSS variable. Could you have changed that variable to make the underline invisible? Also, it would be helpful if you could make your sample available for others to look at and debug.

No, it is not possible that I overwrote the style. As mentioned, I tried isolating the problem by creating a new Angular 17 application with nothing other than a basic tab group. The issue may be limited to Angular 17 - I've seen it working on GitHub with earlier Angular versions.

Solved: I added this to styles.scss:
.mat-mdc-tab-body-wrapper {
border-top: 1px solid silver;
}
Apparently, the Angular Material demo was created the same way.
